# How to make document clusters using hierarchical clustering

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, hierarchical-clustering, document-classification

I am trying to cluster documents based on their similarity, the idea is to match the similar words in two documents and divide that number with the total number of words in both the documents. Each value is stored in a 2D array:

```
1.0000 0.1548 0.0968 0.0982 0.2750 0.1239 0.0891 0.1565
0.1548 1.0000 0.0960 0.0898 0.1631 0.0756 0.0874 0.2187
0.0957 0.2300 1.0000 0.4964 0.0980 0.2004 0.4582 0.2315
0.0971 0.2234 0.4946 1.0000 0.0995 0.2010 0.4533 0.2244
0.2793 0.1631 0.0986 0.1001 1.0000 0.1324 0.0904 0.1662
0.1726 0.0756 0.2149 0.2157 0.1795 1.0000 0.2019 0.0819
0.0880 0.2108 0.4582 0.4550 0.0899 0.1880 1.0000 0.2124
0.1556 0.2094 0.0950 0.0884 0.1662 0.0764 0.0867 1.0000
```

So if there are 8 documents the result of each document compared with other is stored as in the table above each index of the array shows one document. So document 0,0 1,1 2,2 ... will always have value one because they are same.

How do I cluster similar documents i.e. who's values are close to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting similarity to a distance using e.g.

```
dist = 1 - sim
```

As your similarity is bounded by 1, this should work just fine.

Note that, however, hierarchical clustering does not *scale* well. The usual naive implementation scales with `O(n^3)`, and very careful implementations can run in `O(n^2)` for *some* linkage types (single-link, complete-link, maybe UPGMA too). Nevertheless, your usual text corpus will be way too large to this to be feasible.